# PHP Hierarchical MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to make a query on the database example below where if a particular ID has a parent greater than zero, echo that parent’s NAME.

For example when the query would reach ID #5, under the PARENT I would like to get “Adidas” and not “2”. Right now I get the parent’s ID, but I’d like to go a step further and retrieve the parent’s NAME.

DATABASE EXAMPLE:

```
ID  |  PARENT  |  NAME
———————————————————————
1   |     0    |  Nike
2   |     0    |  Adidas
3   |     1    |  Jordan
4   |     1    |  Bryant
5   |     2    |  Rose
6   |     2    |  Howard
```

Here is the query I am performing as it stands (it's a bit convoluted since I am calling from 2 tables):

```
$q = "SELECT `categories`.`ID`, `categories`.`Parent`, `categories`.`NAME`, 
             `products`.`ID` as `ID2`, `products`.`NAME` 
      FROM `categories`, `products`";
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Is it Categories or Product table?

Comment: You need a joining condition to related the tables, otherwise you get a full cross product.

Comment: it is the Categories table.

Comment: Where is the `products` table? Is it really relevant to this question?

Comment: @Barmar oh ok...I have no idea how to even approach that. Pretty novice to MYSQL

Comment: Then I suggest you learn SQL, and come back when you have some idea of the basics. There are many tutorials on SQL that explain joins.

Comment: @Barmar not really, but I figured I'd show what I have so far. The products table lives inside the same database as the categories

Comment: I meant where is it in the question? Why didn't you show it like you did the `categories` table? Anyway, here's a good web site about hierarchical data: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Surely, it cannot be the remit of SO to provide a personalised introduction to the basics of MySQL (or any other topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired output from the query you need to use [SELF JOIN](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm) in this case as main ID and Parent ID both are in same table.

The query will be

```
SELECT `cat1`.`ID` , `cat1`.`Parent` , `cat2`.`NAME`
FROM `categories` AS cat1
LEFT JOIN `categories` AS cat2 ON `cat2`.`ID` = `cat1`.`PARENT`
```

Categories table has been joined to itself by creating aliases `cat1` and `cat2`.

In this case it is important that from which alias you will get name of the Parent. As ID of second alias cat2 is matched with first alias cat1, you will get the parent category name with second alias.

Hope so it will help you.

Comment: Thank you. Why is it that on the first line you say `cat2`.`NAME`....shouldn't it be `cat1`.`NAME` since I'm still referring to the same table?

Comment: Ok, so you're using cat2.NAME because you're referring to the cloned table titled cat2. By the way this works. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q="select cat1.* from categories cat1 inner join categories cat2 on cat1.PARENT=cat2.ID where cat2.ID=5"
```

You will get an idea from this query.